# Storing Data Temporarily in Django to be accessed across multiple Devices

Tags: django, storage

I am working on an e-learning platform
I have a scenario where a student is doing an timed exam and either their computer crashes or power failure, and hence so computer shuts down
What would be a good way to store this information, such that when the user logs in again to their computer or a different device, they can continue from where they left, with the already answered questions.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using a PWA (Progressive Web App) is the way to go. It does not have to be a total loss of power; even a temporary loss of internet connectivity can cause problems. A PWA can cache the results and sync with the remote server as needed.

Another option is to use a JS framework like alpine/petite-vue to interact with the user and then make a post on submit.

In both cases you can use localstorage to store intermediate results so that the user can continue where they left off.

Comment: the only time i want to sync or send the data to the server is when user has finished the exam or time has run out..

Comment: @kevinochieng have updated my answer with another option.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, the data is sent to database via a post i.e. a submit button on the form.
The issue i am trying to solve is for example the user has attempted 3 out of 10 questions and either the application crashes.
I would like a situation where when the user logs in back to the app, they can continue from the third question as opposed to starting afresh.

Comment: What if user continues on a different device, that data will not be available right?

Comment: Correct. You may also have to deal with the issue of a different user using the same device,

Comment: Let me continue to brainstorm, thank you very much